# Algorithms to use when all predictors are categorical and response is numeric

Tags: algorithm, response, numeric

I have a dataset that has categorical values as predictors; and the response variable is Cost. In other words, my data has the Clinical Risk_levels of a person (say, Hypertension_Risk_Level - Stage-1/Stage-2, etc). My response variable is 'Medical Cost'. All the predictors are categorical in nature. Which algorithm should I use and why. Please advice.

Comment: Is assigning each category values with numbers and inputting them to cost formula not enough?

Comment: It's more promising to ask such questions on [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/). See [Which glm...](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/58861/which-glm-algorithm-to-use-when-predictors-are-numerical-as-well-as-categorical), for example.

Comment: Thanks Stefan and Martheen. Will look at Cross Validated too..